# getting KnockoutJs error You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

When the page loads I get the data by calling getGeneJSONData() and when I do a database udpate i call the same method to load the new data and I get the error "You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element"

Here's the code snips

```
    var geneViewModel = null;

    var Gene = function (data) {
    data = data || {};

    var self = this;
    self.geneValue = data.GeneValue;
    self.geneCode = ko.protectedObservable(data.GeneCode);
    self.geneName = ko.protectedObservable(data.GeneName);
    self.geneComments = ko.protectedObservable(data.GeneComments);

};

var ViewModel = function (items) {
    var self = this;
    var newGene = { "geneValue": "", "geneCode": ko.protectedObservable(null), "geneName": ko.protectedObservable(null), "geneComments": ko.protectedObservable(null) };

    self.genes = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(items, function (data) {
        return new Gene(data);
    }));

self.updateGene = function (gene) {
     getGeneJSONData();
}
}

    function getGeneJSONData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlPath + '/GetGenes',
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (result) {
        if (result) {
            if (result.Success) {
                var geneData = result.Data;

                    geneViewModel = new ViewModel(geneData);
                    ko.applyBindings(geneViewModel);

            }

        }
    });
};

    $(document).ready(function ($) {

    getGeneJSONData();

});
```

I am not sure why I'm getting this error on the data reload. Do I have to remove the bindings before applying them again?

Comment: You only need to apply bindings once.  Instead of creating a new ViewModel for AJAX request, just use the same ViewModel and update its properties.

Comment: because every time you make ajax request, you are calling applybinding don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to apply bindings once. Instead of creating a new ViewModel for AJAX request, just use the same ViewModel and update its properties.

I would suggest that you do this by applying your bindings in your document ready function and passing your ViewModel to your update function. Here is how I would do it:

```
var ViewModel = function(items) {
    var self = this;
    var newGene = {
        "geneValue": "",
        "geneCode": ko.protectedObservable(null),
        "geneName": ko.protectedObservable(null),
        "geneComments": ko.protectedObservable(null)
    };

    self.genes = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(items, function(data) {
        return new Gene(data);
    }));

    //pass in view model here
    self.updateGene = function(gene) {
        getGeneJSONData(self);
    }
}

    function getGeneJSONData(viewModel) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: urlPath + '/GetGenes',
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(result) {
            if (result) {
                if (result.Success) {
                    var geneData = result.Data;
                    viewModel.genes = result.Data

                }

            }
        });
    };

$(document).ready(function($) {
    //apply bindings here
    ko.applyBindings(geneViewModel);
    getGeneJSONData();
});
```

Comment: hi, I created a working example of my initial code here (http://jsfiddle.net/DBBUL/47/)  and then i applied your suggested changes here (http://jsfiddle.net/DBBUL/53/) and the initial data is not being loaded. Not sure why its not working

Comment: The problem is that when you are creating your view model geneData is not defined.

Comment: this seems to work when i have the hardcoded data..but when making the  ajax call with getGeneJSONData the data is not populating

Comment: Open up your developer console and check the console for errors and the network tab to see whats happening with your request.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to call `ko.applyBindings()` repeatedly to refresh your view. Any change in your `ViewModel` is automatically updated in view because of KnockoutJS's automatic dependency tracking. In your case, `ko.applyBindings()` is called whenever the AJAX call is completed. Build a one time solution like for the first time you get the data from the AJAX call, call `ko.applyBindings()` with your viewModel and in subsequent calls, just update the viewmodel.